# Ajax file upload in MVC 4 using jquery.form.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am using MVC . My scenario is like i need to post file and forms variables to controller.

I tried AjaxSubmit which works in all browsers except for IE. It shows "access is denied".

```
    $(".WW_Register_Form").ajaxSubmit({ url: url, type: 'post', enctype: 'multipart/form-data'});
```

My requirements are to post a file and post form parameters in ajax.

Is there any other jquery plugin by which i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably receiving the `access denied` error due to restrictions on `XMLHttpRequests` over cross-domains.

Are you trying to access another domain that isn't of `same-origin`? Even something as simple as removing the `www` off of `www.formsubmit.com` could cause an issue with  your requests and the browser does not see this as a `same-origin`

Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy for clarification.

My suggestion is to make sure that you are trying to contact an application/script that is of same-origin.

Comment: I am using relative url only.

Comment: It happens only when i manually trigger the file upload click using javascript.